# Download on ubuntu terminal proceeding or not

Tags: 10.04

I had put my computer on hibernate mode coz my internet connection had stopped while download was taking place.Now the internet is working.How do i check whether it is downloading?Or do i have to do something to resume the download process?

Answer (score 1):

As you initiated your download from console, you know the command you executed for it. Assuming it is something starting with `wget`, you could check using

```
ps aux|grep wget|grep -v grep
```

This utilises the [ps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ps_%28Unix%29) tool to show the list of running processes for all users in long form (see `man ps` for details), pipes the output to [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) which filters it and leaves only lines containing "wget", and finally pipes it to grep again to filter itself. Now you should see your download process -- or, otherwise, know you've got to start it again.

On the other hand you should see the running process in the terminal window where you executed it -- unless, of course, you "backgrounded" it using the ampersand at the end (e.g. "wget [url] &"). In this case, you can go to the exact terminal window where you started it, and type `fg` to bring it back to foreground.

Third place to look for is where your downloaded files go to. If the download is still running, the files should change.

Comment: @lzzy The command i entered was $repo sync.Right now my terminal is open and i can see the last download status which i saw before hibernating i.e. "Receiving Objects: 76%(3297/4333),155.27 Mib |16kib/sec.Can u please tell me what to do now to check downloading?

Comment: If the sync does not continue, it is probably "hung". I don't know what $repo expands to. But you can use above description here, too, replacing "wget" with e.g. "sync". This way you find the PID of the process, and can terminate it (you can try to kick it softly first: `kill -HUP 123`, if it continues you're fine. If not, `kill 123` should terminate it. If not, `kill -KILL 123` should pull the big gun -- alsways assuming 123 being the PID of your process. Then, simply start the sync again -- it should continue where it stopped before.

Comment: This is what i get with the command: ps aux|grep sync|grep -v grep :-root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    13:01   0:00 [async/mgr]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    13:01   0:00 [sync_supers]
nivedita  1451  0.0  1.0  55364 10508 pts/0    Sl+  13:03   0:10 python -E /home/nivedita/Proj/.repo/repo/main.py --repo-dir=/home/nivedita/Proj/.repo --wrapper-version=1.17 --wrapper-path=/home/nivedita/bin/repo -- sync #--calling-python-from-/bin/sh--

Comment: what should i do now.I dont want to teminate the download process.I want to resume it from the point where it had stopped.can u please help?

Comment: and with the command : ps -A | grep sync i get                    14 ?        00:00:00 async/mgr
   17 ?        00:00:00 sync_supers

Comment: Your comments are hard to read. To post output from commands like this, better use services like [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/), and simply post the URL here as reference. Sure you prefer to resume your process -- but what to do if the process refuses? I guess it was about to sync multiple files, right? So it will resume after a fresh start -- not start from the beginning. Already completed files should not be synced again.

Comment: @lzzy u mean i can close the terminal and fire the same command again to resume the process?and the o/p of commands is here:http://paste.ubuntu.com/1076571/

Comment: Much better :) You could try to send it a wake-up (not sure if it understands it, but it won't hurt) using `kill -HUP 3462`. kill -HUP is normally used to tell a demon (server process) to re-read its configuration and reload/restart itself if needed. According to your paste, the sync process is not doing anything currently ("S" stands for "Sleeping") -- but who "sleeps" may be woken, worth a try. Otherwise: Yes, I'd think so -- but not knowing exactly what it is I can hardly be sure. You didn't answer whether it is syncing multiple files between two directories/machines...

Comment: PS: You don't need to close the terminal to restart the sync. If the HUP (initiated from a second terminal) does not work out, you could simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<KBD>C</kbd> to abort it, or -- if that does not do, issue a `kill -KILL 3462` from the second terminal. You should then see the prompt returning in the sync terminal.

Comment: The cmd $repo sync is to pull down files to your working directory from the repositories.Thanks i'l try this out

Comment: In that case it should be safe to kill the process and start it over, if the `kill -HUP` does not work out. On the other hand, I do not see that you have any other chance in that case, safe or not.